# Как склеить два адреса htacces с символами http?

Tags: .htaccess

собственно вот такой адрес

```
http://filmi-online24.ru/serials/serial-Vavilon%205/
```

на такой

```
http://filmi-online24.ru/serials/serial-Vavilon-5/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант сделать перманентную переадресацию:

```
Redirect 301 /serial-Vavilon%205/ http://filmi-online24.ru/serials/serial-Vavilon-5/
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/serials/serial-Vavilon%205/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://filmi-online24.ru/serials/serial-Vavilon-5/? [R=301,L] я так сделал и неполучается.

Comment: Попробуй прям как я написал копипастом